# Group query results by "today", "in last 7 days", "in last month" and "older"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a simple question related to grouping rows by date with some "narrative" periods.
Let's assume that I have very simple table with articles. ID which is PK, title and date. The date column is datetime / timestamp.

I would like to group somehow my results so I can present them in the view like

**Written today:**

- art 944
- art 943

**Written in last 7 days:**

- art 823
- art 743

**Written in last 30 days:**

- art 520
- art 519
- art 502

**Older:**

- art 4
- art 3
- art 1

Can I achieve that in just one single query with some *group by* statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gordon should have credit for writing this out. But I think you probably just want to append a column with the appropriate descriptor and probably sort them in the order you'd like to see them.

```
select
    title,
    case when date = curdate() then 'today'
         when date >= curdate() - interval 6 day then 'last 7 days'
         when date >= curdate() - interval 29 day then 'last 30 days'
         else 'older'
    end as bucket,

from ...
order by
    case
        when date  = curdate() then 1
        when date >= curdate() - interval 6 day then 2
        when date >= curdate() - interval 29 day then 3
        else 4
    end,
    title ...
```

It looks like you didn't have the titles in alphabetical order. If you want them sorted by age then remove the case expression and just use the date value.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. Case is closed. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement for the grouping column.  Something like this:

```
select (case when date = curdate() then 'today'
             when date >= curdate() - interval 6 day then 'last 7 days'
             when date >= curdate() - interval 29 day then 'last 30 days'
             else 'older'
        end),
       count(*),
       . . .
from . . .
group by (case when date = curdate() then 'today'
               when date >= curdate() - interval 6 day then 'last 7 days'
               when date >= curdate() - interval 29 day then 'last 30 days'
               else 'older'
          end)
```

Comment: OP does want row details so I don't think you want to aggregate. Returning the computed expression and sorting is probably sufficient.

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . Hmm, the question says "I would like to group somehow my results" and then explicitly mentions `group by`.

Comment: I know. And you've got BI tools that use the terminology of "groups" to refer to the concept of sorted data with group headers/footers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon. It was so simple...
That does what I want.

```
select
id,
title,
published_at,
(case
    when published_at > curdate() then 'future article'
    when published_at = curdate() then 'today'
    when published_at >= curdate() - interval 6 day then 'last 7 days'
    when published_at >= curdate() - interval 29 day then 'last 30 days'
    else 'older'
end) as 'when' 
from
    articles
order by
    published_at desc
```